# How to use ajax to display database records using a select list?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have used a select list in my custom form to select a product code and display data corresponding to that code. I am using AJAX for this task but it does not display any record.

```
function webform_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // Change the description of a form element.
  $items['examples/webform_module/report'] = array(
    'title' => 'Report',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('webform_module_report'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 0,
  );
   return $items;
}

function webform_module_report($form, &$form_state) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT o.nid, o.sku FROM {formmodule_order} o ");
  $options = array();

  foreach($result as $row) {
    $options[$row->nid] = $row->sku;  
  }

  $form['select'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Option',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'some-form-results-wrapper',
      'callback' => 'webform_module_display'
    )
  );

  $form['results'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="some-form-results-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );

  // If the form has been submitted, build up your results and display them
  if (isset($form_state['values']['select'])) {
    $rows = db_select('formmodule_order', 't')
      ->fields('t')
      ->condition('t.sku', $form_state['values']['select'])
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();

    $header =  array(t('Product ID'), t('Product Code'), t('Product Stock'), t('Product Purchased'), t('Created'));

    $form['results']['#markup'] = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
  }
  else {
    $form['results']['#markup'] = '<p>The results will appear here when you change the dropdown option.</p>';
  }

  return $form;
}

function webform_module_display($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['results'];    
}
```

**Update**: after debugging the query under if statement `$rows = db_select('formmodule_order', 't') ->fields('t') ->condition('t.sku', $form_state['values']['select']) ->execute() ->fetchAll();` does not print any result. It just says array(). What does that mean?

Comment: After lot of hair pulling i edited my code to this level that its flow is all correct in the sense i want to do but it does not displaying any output

Comment: Debug Advice:

add 'type' => 'item' and '#markup' => '' to your element early state of results element.

$form_state has to be by reference in ajax callback (&$form_state)
dpm($form_state) inside your callback

try to return 'test';
in your callback

Comment: after debugging the query under if statement - $rows = db_select('formmodule_order', 't')
      ->fields('t')
      ->condition('t.sku', $form_state['values']['select'])
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll(); does not print any result. It just say array(). what does that mean

Comment: print_r($rows)?

Comment: @Pan Chrono yes it prints the array as required but does not display it below the header line

Answer (score 0):

### Display recrd from database when selected from select list Using AJAX

### yourmodule.module file

```
<?php
```

**hook_menu implementation**

```
function webform_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // Change the description of a form element.
  $items['examples/webform_module/report'] = array(
    'title' => 'Report',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('webform_module_report'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 0,
  );
   return $items;
}

function webform_module_report($form, &$form_state) {
**query to fetch data in a select list**
$result = db_query("SELECT o.nid, o.sku FROM {formmodule_order} o ");

    $options = array();
   foreach($result as $row) {
      $options[$row->nid] = $row->sku;

    }


 //drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($options, true) . '</pre>');    
 $form['select'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Option',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,    **//option will be displayed here**
    '#ajax' => array(
      'wrapper' => 'some-form-results-wrapper',
      'callback' => 'webform_module_display'
    )
  );
```

**This will form the header of the table below which the data will be displayed**

```
  $form['results'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="some-form-results-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(t('Product ID'), t('Product Code'), t('Product Stock'), t('Product Purchased'), t('Created')),
    '#rows' => array(),

  );
  // drupal_set_message('<pre>header:' . print_r($form['results'], true) . '</pre>');

  **// If the form has been submitted, build up your results and display them**
  if (isset($form_state['values']['select'])) {

    drupal_set_message('<pre>select_option:' . print_r($form_state['values']['select'], true) . '</pre>');

  $query = db_select('formmodule_order', 't')
      ->fields('t')
      ->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['select']);

     $result = $query->execute();
     // drupal_set_message('<pre>option1:' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>');
    **// loop through to display result**
   while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {


    //$debug .= '<br/>Header Record #'.' <pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>';
  $nid = array('#id' => 'id',
                 '#type' => 'markup',
                 '#markup' => '<b>' . $row['nid']. '</b>',
                 );
    //drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($nid, true) . '</pre>');
    $sku = array('#id' => 'sku',
                     '#type' => 'markup',
                    '#markup' => '<b>' . $row['sku'] . '</b>',
                 );
    //drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($sku, true) . '</pre>');
   $orderin = array('#id' => 'orderin',
                 '#type' => 'markup',
                 '#markup' => '<b>' . $row['orderin']. '</b>',
                 );
            //   print_r($orderin);
    //drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($nid, true) . '</pre>');
    $orderout = array('#id' => 'orderout',
                     '#type' => 'markup',
                    '#markup' => '<b>' . $row['orderout'] . '</b>',
                 );
    //drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($orderOut, true) . '</pre>');
    $created = array('#id' => 'created',
                     '#type' => 'markup',
                    '#markup' => '<b>' . $row['created'] . '</b>',
                 );

    $form['results'][] = array('nid' => &$nid,
                                'sku' => &$sku,
                                'orderIn' => &$orderin,
                                'orderOut' => &$orderout,
                                'created' => &$created,
                                );
    $form['results']['#rows'][] = array(array('data' => &$nid),
                                         array('data' => &$sku),
                                         array('data' => &$orderin),
                                        array('data' => &$orderout),
                                         array('data' => &$created),
                                         );
    unset($nid);
    unset($sku);
    unset($orderin);
    unset($orderout);
     unset($created);


    }              


  }


 else {
   $form['results']['#rows'] = '<p>The results will appear here when you change the dropdown option.</p>';
    }

      return $form;
    }

**callback function** 
   function webform_module_display($form, $form_state) {

      return $form['results'];


    }
```